# Using Chart.js version 3, How to left justify the y-axis labels on a stacked bar chart?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.js3, chart.jsv3

I'm using Chart.js version 3. I need to left justify the labels on the y-axis of a stacked bar chart. How do accomplish that?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in the [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/axes/cartesian/#tick-alignment) this can be done using the `crossAlign` property:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      backgroundColor: 'pink'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    indexAxis: 'y',
    scales: {
      y: {
        ticks: {
          crossAlign: 'far'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.6.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Oh, I miss that, my bad.... It appears that the documentation is missing the word "justification". A word popular among designers, front end developers and humans. :)

Comment: Well it is open source so you are always welcome to adjust it even though it's description is still pretty understandable for most humans. It is better is everyone can understand it so you are welcome to put in any pr with changes